# Manage expiration for multiple document types for a set of partners

Tags: saas

We work with a lot of partners and are required to track various certifications for them which expire periodically.

An example would be all of our partners in New York may be required to provide a permit document (expiring at the expiration date on the permit) and a COI document (expiring six months after it's provided), while a partner in Chicago would be required to provide a license and a COI, each with their own expiration dates.

We do this for a few hundred partners across about a dozen different cities, with each city having its own specific required documents / certifications.

We want to be able to:

- set which certifications are required for different partner types based on location
- track which partners have all of their required certifications, and
- be able to follow-up on them as they expire.

Ideally,

- we could automate the notices to partners about expired / missing required certifications
- partners would be able to upload the docs themselves, which we could then approve or edit as necessary
- we could pull the data into our existing reporting environment so we could make Tableau reports off of it

Currently, this is tracked in a spreadsheet and a shared folder, but that's obviously not scalable and is error prone.

Answer (score 0):

## EPIM

[EssentialPIM](https://www.essentialpim.com) is a commercial personal information manager that might allow you to do what you want.

You can setup contacts for your various partners and clients, and you can set up Notes for the multitude of certifications and documents required.

You can use Tasks with due dates for expiration of said documents, or set up calendar events for important dates, and get reminders for any required actions.

Cross linking various items together with tags to create relationships between multiple partners, tasks, and documents will help establish connections between various assets.

It runs on Windows or Android, and you can do local sync it without sharing data with "third party clouds".

The [business edition](https://www.essentialpim.com/pc-version/business-edition) allows multi-user access to a central database for collaboration if multiple users need to modify/access this data.

## TiddlyWiki

If you want a more DYI approach you can look into [TiddlyWiki](https://tiddlywiki.com) a multi functional web based note book and wiki.

You wont get any reminders or due dates or other conveniences out of the box, bu if you are willing to roll you sleeves up and prefer to custom code your own system, its extensibility will win over any pre-made solution.

Using the versatile [tagging system](https://tiddlywiki.com/#Tagging) you can build a complex network of relationships between *Tiddlers* (fundamental block of information) and use the smart [filtering system](https://tiddlywiki.com/#Filters) to build templates of information for each partner or document.

You can install it over a local server [running node.js](https://tiddlywiki.com/#GettingStarted%20-%20Node.js) for collaboration and open in on any modern platform with a web browser.